# html_entity_decode does not decode

Tags: php, wordpress, html-encode

I have a problem with decoding html entities for browser display.
I'm trying to display the blog description from a wordpress blog. The text is being html entity encoded before it is saved in the db. So in order to display, for instance, a hyper link the text has to be html entity decoded back, so the a-tag is being rendered properly.

But when I try to decode the text it still comes out as html entities.

The output before being decoded:

```
echo(bloginfo( 'description' )); //output: Display a hyper link. &lt;a href=""&gt;READ MORE&lt;/a&gt;
```

The output when being decoded. And here's my problem. It is still not decoded! Check the output.

```
echo(html_entity_decode(bloginfo( 'description' ))); //output: Display a hyper link. &lt;a href=""&gt;READ MORE&lt;/a&gt;
```

And when I try to hard code the text to be decoded, it works!

```
echo(html_entity_decode('Display a hyper link. &lt;a href=""&gt;READ MORE&lt;/a&gt;')); //output: Display a hyper link. <a href="">READ MORE</a>
```

I've looked at the php manual, and tried different charsets and quote styles as arguments. But still no luck.

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) function does not return the text, it echoes it directly. Your "echo" will therefore in fact echo nothing!

Use [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the Wordpress manual :)

It clearly states it prints the results to the browser, use get_bloginfo instead.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

For clarity, it doesnt work because bloginfo echo's the information, it doesnt return it at all. You could have tested this by checking (by using var_dump) the return value of bloginfo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `bloginfo` does not encode the characters another time?

If it re-encodes them, your `html_entity_decode` will simply revert back to their original status (which is encoded).